# "Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component" after updating firebase database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-router

I'm trying to update some data to my firebase database on form submit, but when I click submit I get the following warning:

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
>   application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
>   in the componentWillUnmount method.

Below is the code that gets executed on submit. If I remove the update code the warning goes away but I need to save the data how can I fix this?

```
handleRewardFormSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const self = this;
        let points = 0;
        const memberId = this.state.selectedMember;
        const groupID = this.state.groupid;
        const selectedPoints = Number(this.state.selectedPoints);
        const memberRef = database
          .ref("members")
          .child(memberId)
          .child("groups")
          .child(groupID);

        const groupRef = database
          .ref("groups")
          .child(groupID)
          .child("members")
          .child(memberId);

        memberRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
          points = snapshot.val().points + selectedPoints;

          // No warning if i remove this
          memberRef.update({
            points: points
          });

          // No warning if i remove this too
          groupRef.update({
            points: points
          });

        });
      };
```

Comment: The code you have included in your question contains no call to either `setState` or `forceUpdate`, so your error is most likely elsewhere.

Comment: I guess this is inside your react component, and I suppose you're attaching a one-time event handler to `memberRef`, in which you call some updates.
Maybe this component gets unmounted by then.

Comment: And the error only shows up if I redirect with react-router